# Why should we wait an additional d-1 surface code cycles in one-cell logical qubit move process of surface code?

Tags: error-correction, surface-code

I was reading [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.0928) paper.

In section XIII-A, after we finish two surface code cycles for a one-cell logical qubit move, it says "To establish all stabilizer values in time, we then wait an additional d − 1 surface code cycles."

Then why the additional cycles are required?

Answer (score 2):

You might find the paper ["Stability Experiments: The Overlooked Dual of Memory Experiments"](https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2022-08-24-786/) helpful.

What it comes down to is that there are two observables to move, X and Z. One is aligned along the move and the other is aligned against. To move the one aligned along the move, the data qubits being crossed must be initialized (and later measured) in the same basis as that observable. To move the one aligned against the move, you must multiply stabilizers of that basis into the observable to push it across the movement. But because the data qubits along the movement were initialized in the other basis, these stabilizer values are initially random projections. You have no way to tell if they're right or wrong; a single one being wrong will ruin the whole process! So you have to measure them multiple times, so that the number of measurement errors needed to fool you is more than 1.

The stability experiment is just the simplest example of this "determine the global product of a bunch of initially locally random stabilizers" task. When you simulate it you find that increasing the number of rounds of measurements exponentially decreases failure rate at the task, as it would when moving a qubit.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To be able to correct measurement errors the same stabilizers need to be measured $d$ times, such that $\lfloor\frac{d-1}{2} \rfloor$ measurement errors on the same ancilla can be corrected.

In the paper you mention, the stabilizer is measured once to complete the physical operation, and then additionally $d-1$ times, such that it is measured $d$ times in total.